# How to create custom components for Rechart components

Tags: recharts

Lets say I am creating a bar chart using Recharts, how would i create a custom component for each of the following Recharts components:

XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, Legend, CartesianGrid, Cell, and Bar

The reason for this s because i am planning to create a chart with a lot of props and wish to separate all the default props and customization in their own individual component for the list component above.

I have tried just putting the CartesianGrid in a react component and the grid will not show

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

It seems that you want to wrap the existing Recharts provided components in a custom component for better organization of your code.

This is currently not supported directly by Recharts, as they check for the type of element that you are rendering and if it does not match one of the allowed types it does not get rendered.

For ex:

```
<LineChart>
    <Line></Line>
</LineChart>
```

would display a line correctly,
But

```
function MyLine(props) {
    return <Line></Line>
}

<LineChart>
    <MyLine />
<LineChart>
```

would not render the line.

This is because, recharts figures out that the MyLine component is not allowed and hence would not be displayed.

This is a big problem as it does not allow us to reuse or compose components.
But there are some workarounds, one of them being calling your custom component as a function directly:

```
<LineChart>
{
    MyLine({})
}
</LineChart>
```

It also seems like there are no plans to provide such an api in future. All such issues on their github are already closed, without providing a solution.

- https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/412
- https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/41
- https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1470

Comment: sucks!  I'm facing this issue now.  SimpleLineChart won't render within another custom component.  After trying your solution of calling it as a function directly, it didn't work and I got this error: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

Comment: Calling the component as a function worked, thank you 

Comment: This is absolutely wonderful! Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that the provided solution is not equivalent to rendering a separate component - if you use hooks inside `MyLine` and return before the `LineChart`, you'll get an error about different number of hooks used